# Multilinestring to Linestrings

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I'm looking for a way to split **MULTILINESTRING** into multiple **LINESTRINGS** using the spatial function of MS SQL. In my table, I have column geometry that makes it easy to get to a string value using the .ToString () function. But I'm looking for the **MULTILINESTRING** divided into **LINESTRINGS** **function**.
Do you have any ideas, please?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have another question, when I have one really long **LINESTRING** and I want to split them into several shorter **LINE**s like on picture below is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @geom geometry = 'MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 5 5), (1 3, 3 1), (-5 3, -8 -2))'; 
select @geom.STGeometryN(n.rownum).ToString() as Linestring
from
(
    select top (@geom.STNumGeometries()) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as rownum
    from sys.all_objects
) as n;
```

**EDIT:**

```
declare @g geometry = 'LINESTRING(1 1, 2 3, 4 8, -6 3, 5 2, -4 15)';

select 
geometry::STLineFromText(concat('LINESTRING(', @g.STPointN(n.rownum).STX, ' ', @g.STPointN(n.rownum).STY, ',', @g.STPointN(n.rownum+1).STX, ' ', @g.STPointN(n.rownum+1).STY, ')'), 0)
from
(
    select top (@g.STNumPoints()-1) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as rownum
    from sys.all_objects
) as n;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I'll check it and turn back on you with some questions maybe, but really thanks

Comment: OK that helped a lot but I have another tricky question. I edited my previous question can you please look at that ? Thanks